# How do I get the version string from a remote windows box from a Mac or Windows box through python3

Tags: python-3.x, windows

Is there a method to ask a remote Windows box what its current version of the operating system is from a Mac or Windows box running Python3?

Normally on a local Windows box my script calls ver and I then parse the result for the actual version.  For remote systems on Linux and Macintosh I do the following

**On Linux**:

```
err, release = DoRemoteSubProcess( ip, ['lsb_release -r']) # Release: 7.6.1810
return release.strip()
```

**On Darwin**:

```
err, release = DoRemoteSubProcess( ip, ['sw_vers -productVersion'])  # 10.15.3
return release.split(':')[1].strip()
```

My function DoRemoteSubProcess() performs a remote secure shell call to the given IP.

For Mac and Linux I get the remote computers version string.  Is there something equivalent on Windows?  My script can be run from a Macintosh or Windows box.

Comment: Essentially, you are asking about a command line tool for Windows that prints the OS version. Doesn't read like a programming question.

Comment: @linspeactable Any python style programming method would do.  I'm looking for an answer NOT a critique about a method.  This is a real problem for me otherwise I would not ask.  A CLI method probably would NOT work since Windows doesn't have a built in method equal to ssh.

Comment: @IInspectable:  Sorry misspelled your named above.  TY